# How is my local git branch "ahead by 28" when it's actually only ahead by 1?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I merged `origin/master` into a feature branch and suddenly git is telling me my local feature branch is ahead by 28 commits. I don't see why; it seems to be just 1 ahead:

```
>git branch -v
  ...
* dev/feature1 3a18afa [ahead 28] Merge remote-tracking branch
                                  'origin/master' into dev/feature1


>git branch -rv
  origin/dev/feature1          f3dd065 [...]
  ...


>git log
commit 3a18afa...
Merge: f3dd065 b1255f0
...
```

So `3a18afa` is where my local branch is at, `f3dd065` is the remote branch it's tracking, and `f3dd065` is one of the parents of `3a18afa`.

Why does it say `[ahead 28]`?

Answer (score 3):

dev/feature contains 28 commits, from the other parents, that are not yet pushed to origin/master.

Comment: `origin/master` specifically, or just commits that do not exist in `origin`?

Comment: I think it just counts the commits outstanding on the local side.

Comment: I've just had this again, so I did the following: reset the merge, then pull both branches one at a time, then push origin --all. Then merge again. It was still "10 ahead". Moreover, `git status` is quite specific about this: `On branch master. Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commits.`. That's after I added exactly 1 commit to master. Could it be something else?

Comment: Here are some commands to try which give a good view of your commits. 

'git log --oneline --decorate --graph origin/master master'


or 


'git log --oneline --graph --decorate -40 --branches'


or

'git show-branch master origin/master'

Comment: @romkyns, the 'git show-branch master origin/master' command should show 11 commits (the ten that it is supposedly ahead and one common commit).  if not then I don't know what could be causing the message.

Comment: It shows just two commits: one for [master] and one for [origin/master]. It is true, however, that the total number of commits since the branches diverged was 10/11 (depending on what's counted). So I guess "10 ahead" counts commits from all parents of a merge. One thing that's definitely the case is that all commits other than the merge were pushed to origin.